# fsck ext4 on ssd: max mountcount and checkinterval

Tags: filesystems, ext4, fsck

I'm using an ssd as the only drive in my laptop (Debian stable).
It [seems that SuSE](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/install-boot-login/437298-fsck-not-needed-ext4-filesystems.html) sets mountcount to -1, disabling fsck at boot. The thread linked says that ext4 needn't be fsck'd anyway. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

Like with any other journalling file systems, the need for regularly checking the file system is much less than with e.g. ext2, due to the fact that checking for errors on mount time is much easier - empty log on mount means, that the file system has been unmounted correctly and is thus treated as clean. If the log is found to contain some unfinished tasks, it's up to you what to do with it - but you should be informed of such a state when the file system is being mounted.